# Horário errado no MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Quando coloco no *schema* do MongoDB:

```
created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

A hora está com uma diferença de 3 horas a mais.

Como eu posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `MongoDB` trabalha com UTC, ou seja, fuso horário sem ajustes. Você sempre terá que considerar isso na hora de usar `Date`.

Como no Brasil os fuso horários são de -3h e -4h você sempre verá as horas a mais do que a sua atual.

Infelizmente não há nenhuma maneira real para corrigir essa exibição dentro do `MongoDB` :(, mas se você pensar por outro lado isso também é bom, pois isso significa que você pode ter muitas aplicações em diversos fusos horários e todos eles podem trabalhar a partir de uma data fixa (UTC).

Comment: Obrigado Douglas.

Answer (score 1):

Quanto à leitura, use timezone após a data. P.ex., Brasil GMT-3:00 fica -300. Veja exemplo:

```
{
        $project: {
            "iso_date_field": 1,
            "hour": { $hour: { date: "$iso_date_field", timezone: "-0300" } },
            "hour2": { $hour: { date: ISODate("2020-08-14T02:08:04.000-03:00"), timezone: "-0300" } },
            "hour3": { $hour: { date: new Date(), timezone: "-0300" } }
        }
}
```

Não sei dizer quanto à gravação, mas acho que se deve passar a data normalmente...

Answer (score -2):

Já faz 7 anos a pergunta, mas caso alguém precise

```
created: { type: Date, default: () => Date.now() - 3*60*60*1000 }
```

isso pega a hora atual e coloca no item.
estou usando mongoDB atlas e trato isso na api em node.js

(explicando pq deram downvote sei lá pq, ent vim explicar esses pontos kk)